# a way to show text in text field before user enters data

Tags: jquery

is there a jquery plugin or is it relatively easy to do?

There is a text field where users will be entering an amount.  I want the text field to show '$'..when users click on the text field then '$' will be gone.

Answer (score 1):

I recently asked a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010046/how-can-you-swap-an-input-text-field-to-a-password-area-on-focus-in-jquery), I chose to use the [Watermark plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jquery-watermark).

Answer (score 1):

I imagine something like:

```
$('#myInput').one("click", function() {
    $(this).val('');//empty the prefilled input
});
```

Check out [Events/One](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/one). From the docs:

> Binds a handler to one or more events
>   to be executed once for each matched
>   element.

Answer (score 1):

This one clears the field unless a value has been entered and restores the label on blur if the field is empty:

```
<input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" value="$" />

  $("#amount").focus(function(){
    this.value = this.value == "$" ? '' : this.value;
  }).blur(function(){
    this.value = this.value || "$" ;
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input name=Amount value=$100 type=text onfocus="removeDollar(this)" onblur="setDollar(this)">
<script>

function setDollar(e)
{
    e.value = '$' + e.value;
}

function removeDollar(e)
{
    e.value = e.value.substr(1);
}
</script>
```

Comment: This is meant to show underlying mechanics - attaching events programmatically can be a bit abstract, especially if you get into external js files. I find this code self-evident, and no external libraries needed. Going from this to jQuery is a smaller leap than if you skip this step.

Answer (score -1):

That's just basic HTML & JS...

```
<input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" value="$" onFocus="clearText(this)"/>

function clearText(textField)
{
     if (textField.value == textField.defaultValue)
         textField.value = ""
 }
```

Note: I'm not that familiar with jQuery, so this was just a guess using HTML & JS.  If it's not what you were looking for, sorry.